# Twitter hashtag search in user id list

Tags: twitter

I'd like to find mentions of a hashtag from my friends on Twitter.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=(name)
```

This returns a list of ids. What I'm then looking at doing is searching for a hashtag mention within that list of ids. Something like:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#hashtag IN user_id=(1,2,3,4)
```

One possible (and undesirable) workaround would be to do batch processing of:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=(1,2,3,4 ~ 100)
```

And then construct a query based on the screen names.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is the solution. Nothing native, so this looks like a good way to do it actually.